# Function in button

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I'm working on a wordpress theme and it's really twisted. The problem is I'm comfortable just with html and css, as I'm a code noob, so I would really appreciate your help here.

The problem here is that I want to put a tracking script and a redirect on a specific button. I'd now how to do this if I'd find the button's html form.

But when I go to the code in the page where the button is, this is the only thing showing regarding the button

```
    <?php BookYourTravel_Theme_Utils::render_submit_button("primary-btn", 
    "submit-accommodation-booking", esc_html__('TRIMITE REZERVAREA', 
    'bookyourtravel')); ?>
```

- BookYourTravel is the theme

I know you should maybe see all the files to know what to do, as this doesn't seem as enough info.
But I also have a functions.php file. Should I look there? Do you have any idea where should I go?

Thank you a lot. Really stuck here.

Comment: Better find `render_submit_button` function and paste its code here.

Answer (score -1):

Are you writing the theme yourself or are you working with someone else's theme? If you're working on someone else's theme, I would reccommend looking into building a child theme so if you change some code, the OG theme is still there in it's entirety and if they update the theme, your code wont get destroyed in the update. There are tons of tutorials on how to set up a child theme and theres a plugin that will make it for you called Child Theme Configurator if you're not too keen on doing it yourself.

You should be super careful when you're editing functions in your theme(especially if you're new to PHP), but that's where this html is being generated. One of those functions is the thing that's generating your html. If you find where the function is held, you could probably change it so it echos the extra code you're looking to implement but it would be on every button that this function generates throughout your site.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't really give enough information for us to do anything. So if you are really pulling your hair on this one just replace the old button with a new button that you wrote. I can help you out on that end if you don't know javascript.

Comment: I would replace it, but no, I don't know javascript, and I wouldn't know either where to put it.